# Check if file path is correct without checking if file exists

Tags: java, file-io, directory

I am working on an application installer. The user has to provide a file / directory path that will later be created by the application. I need to check if that path is valid (could exists). The problem is that I can not call file.exists() because it might not exist.

I know I could try to create it and then delete it. If it fails, the path is not valid. But is there a better, simpler way? Also, my work around requires special permissions for my installer which is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your criteria for a valid path.

- If you mean: path is well formed: Use regular expressions
- If you mean: path is available, try
  `!file.exists();`

A regular expression for Unix based systems could be like this: `[^\0]+`

Also,you'll find lots more information in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537772/what-is-the-most-correct-regular-expression-for-a-unix-file-path)

Comment: I mean well formed, but i would resort to regular expressions as a last resort - for a pattern such as a valid path in windows they get big and error prone.