# C# - Regex for file paths e.g. C:\test\test.exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows, regex

I am currently looking for a regex that can help validate a file path e.g.:

```
C:\test\test2\test.exe
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far and some samples of input and expected output?

Comment: Do you need to support UNC paths like `\\server\share\file.txt`?

Comment: the regex `C:\\test\\test2\\test\.exe` validates your path.

Comment: @agent No not really, although wouldn't say no

Comment: @ulrichb I want to validate a generic path, that was only an example.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I decided to post this answer which does use a regular expression.

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$
```

Works for these:

```
\\test\test$\TEST.xls
\\server\share\folder\myfile.txt
\\server\share\myfile.txt
\\123.123.123.123\share\folder\myfile.txt
c:\folder\myfile.txt
c:\folder\myfileWithoutExtension
```

Edit: Added example usage:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch (text, @"^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$"))
{
  // Valid
}
```

*Edit: * This is an approximation of the paths you could see.  If possible, it is probably better to use the Path class or FileInfo class to see if a file or folder exists.

Comment: Thanks, remember to souce where you get stuff from ;)

Comment: @Dan.  Wrote it for my own edification.  Fun!

Comment: Does not work for \\test\test$\TEST.xls - problem with $ character probably there are other bad cases.

Comment: @janisCruzis, thanks for pointing out that case.  I have improved my answer, though you are probably right about other edge cases.

Comment: Your regular expression will NOT work if your path / filename contains blank spaces:

`Regex.IsMatch(@"c:\your folder\sub folder\your file.txt", @"^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$")`

Comment: Your expression will not work if your path has ".", example: "C:\folder.folder\folder.txt"

Answer (score 28):

I would recommend using the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) instead of a Regex if your goal is to work with filenames.

For example, you can call [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) to "verify" a path, as it will raise an `ArgumentException` if the path contains invalid characters, as well as other exceptiosn if the path is too long, etc.  This will handle all of the rules, which will be difficult to get correct with a Regex.

Comment: 59 seconds before my answer of the same thing, Bump for speed!

Comment: Could you provide a validation example please?

Comment: @Dan here is an example, note that the path can be UNC or local: if(Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Windows\win.ini"))) { /*Directory exists and valid*/ }

Comment: The problem is that in some situations (esp. high-performance code) you really don't want to have to catch exceptions to validate user-input. It's disappointing that .NET doesn't have a `Path.TryParse` or `FileInfo.TryParse` method which avoids exceptions entirely. Another reason is if you're using a debugger then every time `Path`'s constructor throws an `ArgumentException` the debugger will break - and while you can opt to not break on `ArgumentException` it doesn't let you ignore only `ArgumentException` thrown from `Path` - so if you're SOL if you need to break elsewhere.

Answer (score 16):

This is regular expression for Windows paths:

```
(^([a-z]|[A-Z]):(?=\\(?![\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*])|\/(?![\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*])|$)|^\\(?=[\\\/][^\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*]+)|^(?=(\\|\/)$)|^\.(?=(\\|\/)$)|^\.\.(?=(\\|\/)$)|^(?=(\\|\/)[^\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*]+)|^\.(?=(\\|\/)[^\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*]+)|^\.\.(?=(\\|\/)[^\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*]+))((\\|\/)[^\0-\37<>:"/\\|?*]+|(\\|\/)$)*()$
```

And this is for UNIX/Linux paths

```
^\/$|(^(?=\/)|^\.|^\.\.)(\/(?=[^/\0])[^/\0]+)*\/?$
```

Here are my tests:

[Win Regex](https://regex101.com/r/T8vZNl/8/tests)

[Unix Regex](https://regex101.com/r/wal8VG/33/tests)

**These works with Javascript**

**EDIT**
I've added relative paths, (../, ./, ../something)

**EDIT 2**
I've added paths starting with tilde for unix, (~/, ~, ~/something)

Comment: could you please also make an edit for paths like ~/ ?

Comment: @BogdanPopa Done! :)

Comment: Pasting this into Regex101 throws un-escaped delimiter errors.

Comment: This expression incorrectly validates `\\192.168.0.1\INVALID SHARE\` The share name cannot include spaces in UNC paths.

Comment: This is not valid .NET regex (the question is explicitly about C#)

Comment: I had never noticed the unit tests function in Regex101, always in a too much of a rush when using the site. Brilliant. Thank you for alerting me to its existence.

Answer (score 7):

The proposed one is not really good, this one I build for XSD, it's Windows specific:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:(\\|\/)|file\:\/\/|\\\\|\.(\/|\\))([^\\\/\:\*\?\<\>\"\|]+(\\|\/){0,1})+$
```

Comment: correction - have to remove " otherwise throws error while using

Comment: This one worked better for me (detected all UNC paths I sent to it), but I'm not familiar enough with regex to know if the " should be removed or escaped (e.g. changed to "" for vb.net). I didn't actually see a difference in testing, the regex worked both ways.

Comment: This fails for `C:/` (also with back slash). Fixed version: `^(?:[A-Z]\:|\.|(?:file\:\/\/|\\\\)[^\\\/\:\*\?\<\>\"\|]+)(?:(?:\\|\/)[^\\\/\:\*\?\<\>\"\|]+)*(?:\\|\/)?$`. This one works under the assumption that in the cases `\\name`, `C:\name`, and `file://name` for all occurences of `name` the same rules apply (i.e. `name` cannot contain any of the characters in `\/:*?<>"|`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one for Windows and Linux support: `((?:[a-zA-Z]\:){0,1}(?:[\\/][\w.]+){1,})`

Comment: what if it is a relative path? e.g. starts with ..?
btw I tried it and it only matches part of the path

Comment: The pattern above lacks a '\' next too the '/' in order to be recognized as regex pattern. The pattern should look like: ((?:[a-zA-Z]\:){0,1}(?:[\\\/][\w.]+){1,})

Answer (score 4):

I use this regex for capturing valid file/folder paths in windows (including UNCs and %variables%), with the exclusion of root paths like "C:\" or "\\serverName"

```
^(([a-zA-Z]:|\\\\\w[ \w\.]*)(\\\w[ \w\.]*|\\%[ \w\.]+%+)+|%[ \w\.]+%(\\\w[ \w\.]*|\\%[ \w\.]+%+)*)
```

this regex does not match leading spaces in path elements, so

- "C:\program files" is matched
- "C:\ pathWithLeadingSpace" is not matched

variables are allowed at any level

- "%program files%" is matched
- "C:\my path with inner spaces\%my var with inner spaces%" is matched

Comment: what about relatives paths?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, a valid point. The "A:-Z:|\\ServerName" prefix would be needed to be made optional.

Answer (score 2):

```
regex CmdPrompt("^([A-Z]:[^\<\>\:\"\|\?\*]+)");
```

Basically we look for everything that's not in the list of forbidden Windows Path Characters:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

Comment: could you add a link to the source please?

Comment: To be pedantic: characters 0 through to 32 are also not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old... but expanding on @agent-j's response I've added named groups, and support for period characters.

```
^(?<ParentPath>(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\s\.]+\\[\w\s\.$]+)\\(?:[\w\s\.]+\\)*)(?<BaseName>[\w\s\.]*?)$
```

I've saved this at [Regexr](https://regexr.com/52is4)

Answer (score 0):

I found most of the answers here to be a little hit or miss.

Found a good solution here though:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/31d2bc84-c948-4914-8a9d-97b9e788b341/validate-a-network-folder-path

Note* - this is only for network shares - not local files

Answer:

```
string pattern = @"^\\{2}[\w-]+(\\{1}(([\w-][\w-\s]*[\w-]+[$$]?)|([\w-][$$]?$)))+";
string[] names = { @"\\my-network\somelocation", @"\\my-network\\somelocation", 
    @"\\\my-network\somelocation", @"my-network\somelocation",
     @"\\my-network\\somelocation",@"\\my-network\somelocation\aa\dd",
     @"\\my-network\somelocation\",@"\\my-network\\somelocation"};
foreach (string name in names)
{
 if (Regex.IsMatch(name, pattern))
 {
  Console.WriteLine(name);
   //Directory.Exists function to check if file exists
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Alexander's Answer + Relative Paths

**Alexander** has the most correct answer thus far since it supports spaces in file names (i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\` will match)... This aims to include relative paths as well.

For example, you can do `cd /` or `cd \` and it does the same thing.

Further more, if you're currently in `C:\some\path\to\some\place` and you type either of those commands, you end up at `C:\`

Even more, you should consider paths, that start with '/' as a root path (to the current drive).

`(?:[a-zA-Z]:(\|/)|file://|\\|.(/|\)|/)([^,\/:*\?\<>\"\|]+(\|/){0,1})`

A Modified version of Alexander's answer, however, we include paths that are relative with no leading `/` or drive letter, as well as `/` with no leading drive letter (relative to the current drive as root).

Comment: This would validate unvalid file paths as: \\, \\\, C:\a\\ and it doesn't validate these: C:, C:\folder.something, C:\.folder: https://regex101.com/r/7UgtQA/2/tests