# regular expression to match file path in java

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Regex for file paths e.g. C:\test\test.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416065/c-sharp-regex-for-file-paths-e-g-c-test-test-exe)

I was trying out to create a regular expression to match file path in java

Like `C:/WINDOWS/Profiles/myComputer/Desktop/test.xml`

Pls help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you need a regular expression? Moreover, this is going to give you trouble - the characters allowed are system-dependent; notably, there's File.separator, and some systems allow :, others do not.

Comment: @see [File.exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()).

Answer (score 1):

you could try this,

```
 (?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(?i)(txt|xml|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$
```

Explanation:

```
^(?:[\w]\:|\\) -- Begin with x:\ or \\
[a-z_\-\s0-9\.] -- valid characters are a-z| 0-9|-|.|_ (you can add more)
(?i) -- regular expression case-insensitive
(txt|xml|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx) -- Valid extension (you can add more)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this

```
"([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+\\\\?"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher ma = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]:(?:/[\\w\\s]+)*/[\\w\\s]+\\.\\w+)")
                .matcher("C:/WINDOWS/Profiles/myComputer/Desktop/test.xml");
while (ma.find()) {
    System.out.println(ma.group(1));
}
```

Here's an example working for your case. maybe you need to add some characters that aren't allowed but it's just adding chars in [\w\s.] <- that would accept dots too.