# Java regular expression for file path

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am developing an application a where user need to supply local file location or remote file location. I have to do some validation on this file location.
Below is the requirement to validate the file location.

Path doesn't contain special characters `*` `|` `"` `<` `>` `?`.
And path like "c:" is also not valid.

Paths like

- `c:\`,
- `c:\newfolder`,
- `\\casdfhn\share`

are valid while

- `c:`
- `non`,
- `\\casfdhn`

are not.

I have implemented the code based on this requirement:

```
String FILE_LOCATION_PATTERN = "^(?:[\\w]\\:(\\[a-z_\\-\\s0-9\\.]+)*)";
String REMOTE_LOCATION_PATTERN = "\\\\[a-z_\\-\\s0-9\\.]+(\\[a-z_\\-\\s0-9\\.]+)+";

Pattern locationPattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_LOCATION_PATTERN);
Matcher locationMatcher = locationPattern.matcher(iAddress);
if (locationMatcher.matches()) {
    return true;
}

locationPattern = Pattern.compile(REMOTE_LOCATION_PATTERN);
locationMatcher = locationPattern.matcher(iAddress);

return locationMatcher.matches();
```

Test:

```
worklocation'        pass
'C:\dsrasr'          didnt pass  (but should pass)
'C:\saefase\are'     didnt pass  (but should pass)
'\\asfd\sadfasf'     didnt pass  (but should pass)
'\\asfdas'           didnt pass  (but should not pass)
'\\'                 didnt pass  (but should not pass)
'C:'                 passed infact should not pass
```

I tried many regular expression but didn't satisfy the requirement. I am looking for help for this requirement.

Comment: Question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42036026/1951947

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
([A-Z|a-z]:\\[^*|"<>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)
```

The lines highlighted in green and red are those that passed. The non-highlighted lines failed.

*Bear in mind the regex above is not escaped for java*

[image]

Comment: Which tool is this?

Answer (score 1):

from your restrictions this seems very simple.

`^(C:)?(\\[^\\"|^<>?\\s]*)+$`

Starts with C:\ or slash  `^(C:)?\\`

and can have anything other than those special characters for the rest `([^\\"|^<>?\\s\\\])*`

and matches the whole path `$`

Edit: seems C:/ and / were just examples. to allow anything/anything use this:

`^([^\\"|^<>?\\s])*(\\[^\\"|^<>?\\s\\\]*)+$`

Comment: its not necessary to have C: it can be anything

Comment: I also tried this I am getting error: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 27
^([^"|^<>?\s])*\([^"|^<>?\s])*$
                           ^

Comment: I also tried mine on internet it works but didnt in java using pattern class and matcher

Comment: in java did you guys make sure to double escape? the "\" need to be "\\" in java.

Edited the answer to use double escapes

Comment: yeah i made that changes.."^([^\\\"|^<>?\\s])*\\\\([^\\\"|^<>?\\s])*$".. it works fine.. thanks

Comment: but how can i avoid : "\\asdfas" and "\\" this should not pass

Comment: too many escapes. just 2, you have 3.  if you want no double slashes (which are a valid filepath component btw) I will edit it as such.

Comment: valid path is c:\,
c:\newfolder,
\\casdfhn\share