# Python os.path.basename, strip parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, filepath, os.path

How do I find out the basename of the file in this case?

```
>>> from os.path import basename
>>> basename('C:\\test.exe --help')
'test.exe --help'
```

Result should be just `test.exe` without `--help` or any other arguments.

Comment: `re.match(r'(.*?)\s-', basename('C:\\test.exe --help')).group(1)`

Comment: What is the use case of this? Since you are typing your command with parameters  you might as well not type the parameters so that basename work as intended. Otherwise please explain how does your python program get this command with parameters? Using basename-regular-expression acrobatics is a sign that something can be made simpler elsewhere.

Comment: The user specifies a command (the given string) and I run it using `subprocess.Popen`. In addition I want to log the name of the executed file (`test.exe`) to log (something like `sucessfully called test.exe`). The solution should work with any possible input that `subprocess.Popen` can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module that mimics behaviour of a **Unix** shell (but since command.com used to mimic some of its features, it should work too). It'll also will tolerate a quotes (but note that I used raw strings in example):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> print shlex.split(r'C:\\test.exe --help')
['C:\\test.exe', '--help']
>>> print shlex.split(r'"C:\\test.exe" --help')
['C:\\test.exe', '--help']
>>> print shlex.split(r'"C:\\Program Files\\test.exe" --help')
['C:\\Program Files\\test.exe', '--help']
```

So take first string returned from `shlex.split`, and pass to basename.

If you want to get rid of treating backslashes `\` as escape sequences, you should construct `shlex` object explicitly:

```
>>> from shlex import shlex
>>> lex = shlex('C:\\test.exe --help')
>>> lex.whitespace_split = True
>>> lex.escape = ''
>>> list(lex)
['C:\\test.exe', '--help']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that, at least on Linux, 'test.exe --exe' is a valid filename. So that is the reason why python does not try to clean filenames from 'parameters'. I looked at [windows docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it looks like you also make file named 'test.exe --exe'. So, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Also have a look at this: [What is the most correct regular expression for a UNIX file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537772/what-is-the-most-correct-regular-expression-for-a-unix-file-path)

You should then probably check if file exists, if it does not then use regular expression or the shlex module to strip the parameters...

Comment: That's not exactly true. `test.exe --exe` is also a valid filename on Windows. Running `test.exe --exe` both on Linux and Windows would open `test.exe` not `test.exe --exe` unless you quote or escape it. There is not difference between Windows and Linux at this point. The only difference I found is that `test.exe/test` (no space between `test.exe` and `/test`) would call `test.exe` with `/test` as argument on Windows but not on Linux, however I think that happens rare enough to ignore it in my case.

Comment: test.exe\ --exe would be considered filename in bash, test.exe --exe would not.

Comment: Like I said, escape (`test.exe\ --exe`) or quote (`"test.exe --exe"`).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, shlex
print(os.path.basename(shlex.split(r'"C:\\test.exe" --help')[0]))
```

Comment: This returns the basename of the current file but not of `C:\\test.exe --help`.