# need powershell script to validate user input for valid unix path

Tags: regex, powershell, validation, github, user-input

I need to validate if the user has input valid unix path syntax and not the actual path on the host machine.

There can be single or multiple paths separated by comma or white space and enclosed in either single quotes, double quotes, or no quotes at all.

powershell attempt below fails to validate the above conditions:

```
  - name: Validate Inputs

    run: |

      $inputPaths = "${{ inputs.source_files }}"

      # Check if the input is not empty

      if (-not $inputPaths) {
        echo "Error: 'paths' input is required."
        exit 1
      }

      # Check syntax of each provided path
      $pathsArray = $inputPaths -split ',| '

      foreach ($path in $pathsArray) {

        if (-not ($path -match "^[a-zA-Z]:\\|\\\\|/'[^'\s].*'$|^[a-zA-Z]:\\|\\\\|/\"[^\"\s].*\"$|^[a-zA-Z]:\\|\\\\|/[^'\s]+$")) {
          echo "Error: '$path' is not a valid absolute path syntax."
          exit 1

        }
      }

      echo "Inputs have valid syntax.
```

valid inputs are

```
/tmp/mydir
'/tmp/my  dir1'
"/tmp/my  dir2"
/tmp/mydir '/tmp/my  dir1' '/tmp/my  dir2'
'/tmp/my  dir1','/tmp/my  dir2'
```

Invalid inputs:

```
'/tmp/my  dir1,/tmp/my  dir2'
/tmp/my  dir1
'/tmp/my  dir1
/tmp/my  dir1'
```

I tried validating the quotes but it errors on a valid quote:

```
$paths = "'/u/marsh/UNX/scripts/testscript/test_maillist.txt' '/pathx with space/file1' '/path,with,commas/file2' ""/double quoted path/file3"" ""/path with space/file4"" 'single quoted path/file5' /pathx with space/file1"

# Split paths by whitespace or comma while preserving paths enclosed in quotes

$splitPaths = $paths -split "(?<=\S)\s+|(?<=\S),"

foreach ($path in $splitPaths) {

    # Check if the path is enclosed in single or double quotes

    if (-not (($path -like "'*'") -or ($path -like '"*"'))) {

        Write-Host "Error: Path '$path' is not enclosed in single or double quotes."
        exit 1
    }

    # Remove leading and trailing quotes

    $cleanPath = $path.Trim("'").Trim('"')  

    Write-Host "Cleaned Path: $cleanPath"

}
```

Error  output when it should not have:

```
Cleaned Path: /u/marsh/UNX/scripts/testscript/test_maillist.txt
Error: Path ''/pathx' is not enclosed in single or double quotes.
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Is there some subtle difference between a "valid UNIX path" and an "actual path" on the machine? One would think that an actual path would be valid. Are you wanting to validate UNIX paths when run on Windows? Is the regex pattern identifying single letter "drives"? Does `Resolve-Path` offer anything useful?

Comment: @lit I don't need to `Resolve-Path` for `actual path` becoz the validation for UNIX path has to be done on a windows github runner using PowerShell. So only syntax checks like 1. The path should not be empty. 2. it should start with `/` and other conditions mentioned in the original post have to be checked and not the actual existence of the path which will be handled later in my workflow.

Comment: Is it necessary to validate? In a lot of cases there are validations done when paths are used (creates/read/write...) and you should as well have try catch. So you might have double validation. Should the validation respect file system specific disallowed paths? The correct answer ist different, depending on the details what you want to do after the validation. To understand what I mean read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537772/what-is-the-most-correct-regular-expression-for-a-unix-file-path

Comment: @An-dir most solutions discussed on this thread and likewise are about valid windows and Unix paths where as this specific post is for valid paths separated by comma or whitespace and enclosed within single or double quotes. There seems no solution for checking quotes for validity like there should me closing quote for every open quotes

Comment: @An-dir i updated the original post with the validation for quotes that is failing.

Comment: Quotes are perfectly valid in Unix file names; the only invalid character is the null character (and, of course, a directory entry cannot contain a literal slash as part of its name). There is no rhyme or reason in your examples without addititonal artificial constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your input paths are in the form of *lists* of *string literals* and/or *barewords*:

- One of your invalid path examples - `'/tmp/my  dir1,/tmp/my  dir2'` - seems to impose a non-obvious constraint on your validation:

  - Verbatim `/tmp/my  dir1,/tmp/my  dir2` is formally a valid *single* path, given that `,` is a legitimate character in file names.

    - Fundamentally, as [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) points out, technically it is only `NUL` (the character with code point `0x0`) that is invalid in paths in file-systems on Unix-like platforms.
  - The solution below therefore disallows the presence of verbatim `,` in a single path - adjust as needed.

The following **solution** uses a **two-step approach**:

- It first parses a *list* of paths into the *verbatim* items it represents, via a direct call to the [`[regex]::Match()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match) API.

  - For an explanation of the regex used with `[regex]::Match()` and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/aSAkfe/2).
  - Note its **limitation**: For (relative) simplicity, it only supports *embedded* quoting in the form of using the quotation marks *not* used by the outer quoting (e.g.,
    `'/foo/3" of snow'` or `"/foo/3'o clock"`), but not also *escaped* embedded quoting (e.g., `` "/foo/3`" of snow" `` or `'/foo/3''o clock'`)
- It then validates each item with respect to whether it represents an *absolute Unix-format path*, using PowerShell's [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator.

  - For an explanation of the regex used with `-match` and the option to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/AQ1qEr/1).

```bash
# Sample input paths.
@(
  # --- valid
  '/tmp/mydir'
  "'/tmp/my  dir1'"
  '"/tmp/my  dir2"'
  "/tmp/mydir '/tmp/my  dir1' '/tmp/my  dir2'"
  "'/tmp/my  dir1','/tmp/my  dir2'"
  # --- invalid
  "'/tmp/my  dir1,/tmp/my  dir2'"
  '/tmp/my  dir1'  # partly valid (1st token)
  "'/tmp/my  dir1"
  "/tmp/my  dir1'"  
) | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # Parse each string as a comma- or whitespace-separated list composed of
    # string literals and/or barewords.
    $match = [regex]::Match(
      $_,
      '^\s*((?:(?<item>[^"''\s,]+)|(?<quote>["''])(?<item>.*?)\<quote>)(?:(?:\s*,?\s*)|$))+$'
    )
    if (-not $match.Success) {
      # Not a well-formed list of string literals and barewords:
      # Report the entire string as invalid.
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Path  = $_
        Valid = $false
      }
    }
    else {
      # List of string literals and barewords, validate each list item.
      $match.Groups['item'].Captures.Value | 
        ForEach-Object {
          [pscustomobject] @{
            Path  = $_
            # To allow "," in paths, remove "," from the regex below.
            Valid = $_ -match '^/(?:[^/\0,]+/?)*$'
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Output (note that each output line represents an (successfully parsed) *individual* path):

```
Path                        Valid
----                        -----
/tmp/mydir                   True
/tmp/my  dir1                True
/tmp/my  dir2                True
/tmp/mydir                   True
/tmp/my  dir1                True
/tmp/my  dir2                True
/tmp/my  dir1                True
/tmp/my  dir2                True
/tmp/my  dir1,/tmp/my  dir2 False
/tmp/my                      True
dir1                        False
'/tmp/my  dir1              False
/tmp/my  dir1'              False
```

Comment: it works but can you suggest what changes if the input path is a variable say `$userinput = "/tmp/mydir '/tmp/my  dir1' '/tmp/my  dir2'"`. I'm new to powershell so I may struggle to tweak your script [solution]

Comment: @Ashar: Your example works with the above solution too: it parses the string value into `/tmp/mydir`, `/tmp/my  dir1` and `/tmp/my  dir2`, all of which are valid, absolute Unix-format paths. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: That exactly what I'm looking for but instead of `# Sample input paths.
@( .... )` can you suggest if the path is assigned to a variable like this `$userinput = "/tmp/mydir '/tmp/my  dir1' '/tmp/my  dir2'"` how will it be handled in your script

Comment: @Ashar: In lieu of the entire `@(...)` [array subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) above, provide `"/tmp/mydir '/tmp/my  dir1' '/tmp/my  dir2'"`  (or `$userInput`) as the input to the `ForEach-Object` call, and you'll see that it is handled as expected.

Comment: works !! thank you